# What are they downsides of composite body circ pumps?

Tags: plumbing, pump

I'm going to be replacing some potable water recirculating pumps and I noticed that the Taco 006e3 appears to be a completely nonmetallic system.

This pump's curves fit my needs but I've never used a composite pump like this.

What are the downsides? I'd otherwise be looking at stainless steel pumps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only downside would be not knowing how well it will *really* hold up, as a new-ish product. So check the warranty. A stainless pump body lasts a long, long time, as an established fact. Plastic products (pardon, reinforced composite plastic products) may also last a long time, or they may get old and brittle and fail in ways stainless won't - it's unknown to the end consumer at this point if that will prove to be an issue in 10 years with this model, and I can't find anything on Taco's site mentioning the length of warranty.

Three years appears to be the length of warranty, per this document: https://api.ferguson.com/dar-step-service/Query?ASSET_ID=3777869&USE_TYPE=INSTALLATION&PRODUCT_ID=7628875

Obvious upsides are nothing to corrode and considerably less expensive to produce than stainless/bronze - assuming they pass that savings onto you in the form of a lower price than a stainless/bronze model.